# Show that $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, $f(x)=x^2$ is not onto

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

To begin, the definition of an onto (surjective) function is as follows.

A function $\phi$ from $A$ to $B$ is surjective if for each for each $b$ in $B$, there exists at least one $a$ in $A$ such that $\phi(a)=b$.

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ and $x\in \mathbb{N}$ and $y\in \mathbb{N}$.

We have that $y=f(x)=x^2$, which gives $x=\pm  \sqrt y$.

If $x=- \sqrt y$, we have that $y=x^2$. And if $x = \sqrt y$, we have that $y=x^2$.

This shows there is at least one element $x$ that is the pre-image of an element $y$. I don't see how this function can be proven to be not-onto.

Comment: Your definition of surjectivity is weird.

Comment: I've rewritten it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This shows there is at least one element $x$ that is the pre-image of an element $y$

That is correct, but not necessarily an element $x$ in your domain of $\mathbb{N}$.

Indeed, if $y$ is not a perfect square, then $x$ is not in $\mathbb{N}$.

---

To prove that it is not surjective, it is not so hard with a counter-example:

There is no $x \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $f(x) = 2$. Thus $f$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: Suppose then the function is a mapping from R to R. 
Am I right to say then the function is 'onto'?

Comment: No, because there is no real number whose square is, for example, $-1$.

Comment: is the square of -1 and 1 not 1?

Comment: @user: He said there's no real number whose square is $-1$, not that there isn't a real number that is the square *of* $-1$.  And at any rate, that $(-1)^2 = 1^2 = 1$ only shows that $x^2$ is also not an injection (not one-to-one).  If you define $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \geq 0\}$, then $f: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ defined by $f(x) = x^2$ is a bijection: both a surjection and an injection.

Comment: @BrianTung Got it. I read "1" instead of "-1". 
It is true then there for x in R, there exists no x such that $x^2=-1$$

Comment: Ahh, you thought the minus sign was a dash! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take $y$ to be a square-free natural number, then there isn't any natural number $x$ such that $f(x)=y$ (For example, can you find any natural number such that square of it is equal to 2?). So $f$ can't be onto.

Comment: I see that but I want to see the proof symbolically.

Comment: Well think about it this way: By definition, a natural number $y$ is a square if there exists another natural number $x$ such that $y=x^2$. So what is the negation of this statement?

Comment: If there exists no $$x^2$$, then, there exists no y.

Comment: @user: No, I think Jimmy means that all you need to show is that there exists at least one non-square: a number $y$ for which there exists no natural number $x$ such that $x^2 = y$.  Such a $y$ would be an instance of an element in the range of $f$ for which there is no pre-image in the domain of $f$, and therefore $f$ is not surjective.  He further suggests that $2$ is such a number.  I don't know how rigorous you need to be for your work (do you need to show that there is no natural number whose square is $2$?), but it seems your path is otherwise straightforward.

Comment: @BrianTung So the proof is by counterexample?

Comment: @JimmyM.N. I think you mean that $y$ is not a perfect square, not that it is "square-free"

Comment: @Soke: He might, although certainly it's true that if $y$ is square-free, it works as a counter-example.

Comment: @user: Essentially, yes.  But that's natural, since the definition of a surjection is of the form "For all $x$ in the range of $f$, [some predicate of $x$]".  The easiest way to prove it's not a surjection is to find an $x$ for which that predicate isn't true.

Comment: @BrianTung Yeah, but I could also say "if $y$ is equal to $2$" instead of "$y $ is square-free" and it would work as a counter-example, but it would make more sense to say that "$y$ is not a perfect square" since that is the property that matters here :)

Comment: @Soke: I don't disagree.  I'm just pointing out that his line of reasoning is sound, even if it doesn't pick out the exact salient property.